# How to add a function in another function with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to call a function into another function in Vue.js.
In component 1 I have this function

```
school(){
   return this.project.meta.school
},
```

In component 2 this:

```
shareToEmail() {
    this.from = this.user ? this.user.firstname || this.user.email : this.from
    lib.api().request('get', '/api/project/'+this.project._id+'/share?email='+this.email+'&from='+encodeURI(this.from) )
        .then( (result) => {
            this.state = 'emaildone'
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            alert("Helaas is er geen emailtje verstuurd naar '"+this.email+"'.<br><br>Controleer je emailadres of neem contact op met ons.")
        })
},
```

I will like to add function 1 to function 2, to call from function 2 fucntion 1.

Comment: If you want to call another function then, in function 2, just simply call like this - `this.function1()`

Comment: Look like you're trying to share data between components. You could look into Vuex, or create a global event bus to emit an event from component 1 which gets picked up by component 2.
Do the 2 components have the same parent? You could then emit an event to the parent, which in turn sets the value to component 2